# <textarea> box to increase height (wrap) when the current text overflows the given width?

Tags: css

Is there a css (non-js) solution to have my  box to increase height (wrap) when the current text overflows the given width?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No. The contents in the `input` box are in no relation to the width of the box itself, and there is no CSS property to make it so. You will need to use JavaScript for this.

Answer (score 0):

In short the answers no.

This would be doable with Javascript though. Why do you need a non-js answer?

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be achieved through CSS but you can go for a ONE-liner plugin `Elastic`, you can see the demo [here](http://unwrongest.com/projects/elastic/)
and download [here](http://jquery-elastic.googlecode.com/files/jquery.elastic-1.6.9.zip)

Comment: This uses a JQuery/Javascript libary which the not what the OP is asking for.

Comment: But css cannot achieve that, so i provided the Jquery alternative.

Comment: oopss made a typo. Corrected it.

Comment: Then please dont forget to mark the answer as correct if you like it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Given that you want to increase text area in its height. It is possible at CSS3 supporting browsers like FF4. You can also control the direction of which it can be resized.

Another of the CSS3 solution can be using `contenteditable` element, instead of textarea, which will make how you want possible without using any javascript?

I might show you some examples if this is what you want.